# How do I change my java code to use replset? with Spring Data and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I would like to know how to change my java code to support replset with spring-data and MongoDB.

I have 3 MongoDB servers running.. example:

```
./mongod --dbpath=/home/jsmith/tmp/db1 --replSet=spring --port=27017
./mongod --dbpath=/home/jsmith/tmp/db2 --replSet=spring --port=27027
./mongod --dbpath=/home/jsmith/tmp/db3 --replSet=spring --port=27037
```

if I do rs.status() I can see that if the db on 27017 goes down then one of the others become primary so I know that mongoDB is working right but in my java code if I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/demo
```

Its looking only on port 27017

here is my mongodbconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MongoDBApp.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo";
    }



    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
                return new Mongo(new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {{ add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27027)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27037)); }});

    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.xxxx.mongodb.example.domain";
    }

}
```

how do I change it to support replset? but if its reading and one of the servers goes down I get a error.. anyway to make in reconnect?

Comment: Try to use this config on mongo() method: `return new Mongo(new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {{ add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27027)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27037)); }});`

Comment: no good. did not work

Comment: Wierd.. I set up a replica set and used the code above and worked perfectly for me. Did you initialize the replica set properly? `rs.initiate( configuration )`

Comment: the issue is that if the main node goes down everything crashes I want it to reconnect some how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
    String mongoURI="mongodb://myUsrName:pass@mongoServer-001.company.com:27017,mongoServer-002.company.com:27017,mongoServer-003.company.com:27017/myDBname?waitqueuemultiple=1500&amp;w=1&amp;maxpoolsize=40&amp;safe=true";
    MongoURI uri = new MongoURI(mongoURI);
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo(uri);
```

I specify the 3 servers in the URI (along with extra parameters like max pool size).
The third server (mongoServer-003) is the arbiter and it doesn't store any info. The arbiter helps in the election of the primary server when the current primary goes down. Take a look at [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/).

With this configuration, the app can keep working even if the primary server goes down.

Answer (score 2):

The URI method should work, or there's a clearer way to initialise the replica set using a list of servers:

```
final List<ServerAddress> seeds = Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017),
                                                new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27027),
                                                new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27037));
final Mongo mongo = new Mongo(seeds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the CustomEditorConfigurer and a class that implements PropertyEditorRegistrar.
So you your configuration class needs this:

```
    @Bean
    public static CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer(){
        CustomEditorConfigurer configurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
        configurer.setPropertyEditorRegistrars(
                new PropertyEditorRegistrar[]{new ServerAddressPropertyEditorRegistrar()});
        return configurer;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return authenticationDb;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(host, port)), mongoCredentials(), mongoClientOptions());
        return mongoClient;
    }




public final class ServerAddressPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(ServerAddress[].class, new ServerAddressPropertyEditor());
    }
}
```